# How to translate code from Arduino to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arduino, windows-10, raspberry-pi2, arduino-uno, windows-10-iot-core

I have an Arduino Uno program and want to translate it code a Raspberry Pi 2. I am building a robotic kitchen pantry, and coded an LED state machine in order to represent it. The physical machine I plan to control has two main functions.

**Functions**

(1) The elevator moves to one of these three levels:
 - 0 : Reset / Home
 - 1 : Shelve 1
 - 2 : Shelve 2

(2) The shelves move in/out of the elevator.
 - Mount
 - Unmount

I am currently using LEDs to represent motors / sensors in order to unit test my code. I understand that in order to make my code more robust I will require better handling of timing, something that the Raspberry Pi can afford to do.

Here is my current code:

```
    // Sensors for shelves. True if shelf is loaded.
boolean s1 = false;
boolean s2 = false; 

// Buttons to ask to shelves.
boolean input1 = false;
boolean input2 = false; 

// Elevator level (0, 1, or 2)
int elevator = 0;

// Elevator Level LEDs (Red)
int elevatorReset = 13;
int elevatorOne = 12;
int elevatorTwo = 11;

// Shelve State LEDs (Green) (On if loaded, Off if hidden)
int ShelveOne = 10; // Top Shelve
int ShelveTwo = 9; // Bottom Shelve


// Buttons
int ButtonOne = 2; // Request Shelve One
int ButtonTwo = 3; // Request Shelve Two
int ButtonReset = 4; // Request Reset

// Debouncing
unsigned long lastTime1 = 0;
unsigned long lastTime2 = 0;
const long interval = 300;


void setup() {
pinMode(elevatorReset, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output 
pinMode(elevatorOne, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output 
pinMode(elevatorTwo, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output

pinMode(ShelveOne, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output
pinMode(ShelveTwo, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output

pinMode(ButtonOne, INPUT); // make button 1 an input 
pinMode(ButtonTwo, INPUT); // make button 2 an input 
pinMode(ButtonReset, INPUT); // make button 3 an input 
}

void loop() {

unsigned long currentTime = millis();

level(0);

// Request Shelf 1
if (digitalRead(ButtonOne) == LOW) 
{
  pickup(1);
  deliver(1);
}

// Request Shelf 2
if (digitalRead(ButtonTwo) == LOW)
{
  pickup(2);
  deliver(2);  
}

// Request Reset
if (digitalRead(ButtonReset) == LOW) 
{
  reset();
}

}

void pickup(int num){
  if (num == 1)
  {
    level(0);
    delay(500);
    level(1);
    delay(500);
    load(1);
  }
  else if (num == 2)
  {
    level(0);
    delay(500);
    level(1);
    delay(500);
    level(2);
    delay(500);
    load(2);
  }
  else if (num == 0)
  {

  }
}

void dropoff(int num){
  if (num == 1)
  {
    level(1);
    delay(500);
    unload(1);
  }
  else if (num == 2)
  {
    level(1);
    delay(500);
    level(2);
    delay(500);
    unload(2);
  }
}



void deliver(int num)
{
  if (elevator == 1)
  {
    delay(1000);
    level(0);
    //blink();
  }

  if (elevator == 2)
  {
    delay(1000);
    level(1);
    delay(500);
    level(0);
    //blink();
  }
}

void level(int num)
{
  if (num == 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(elevatorReset, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(elevatorOne, LOW);
    digitalWrite(elevatorTwo, LOW);
    elevator = 0;
  }
  else if (num == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(elevatorReset, LOW);
    digitalWrite(elevatorOne, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(elevatorTwo, LOW);
    elevator = 1;
  }
  else if (num == 2)
  {
    digitalWrite(elevatorReset, LOW);
    digitalWrite(elevatorOne, LOW);
    digitalWrite(elevatorTwo, HIGH);
    elevator = 2;
  }
}

void load(int num){
  if (num == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(ShelveOne, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ShelveTwo, LOW);
    s1 = true;
  }
  else if (num == 2)
  {
    digitalWrite(ShelveOne, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ShelveTwo, HIGH);
    s2 = true;
  }
}

void unload(int num){
  if (num == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(ShelveOne, LOW);
    s1 = false;
  }
  else if (num == 2)
  {
    digitalWrite(ShelveTwo, LOW);
    s2 = false;
  }
}

void reset()
{
if (s1 == true)
        {
            delay(500);
            dropoff(1);
            delay(500);
            level(0);
        }

else if (s2 == true)
        {
            delay(500);
            dropoff(2);
            delay(500);
            level(1);
            delay(500);
            level(0);
        }
}

void blink ()
{
  delay(1000);
  while( !(digitalRead(ButtonOne) == LOW || digitalRead(ButtonTwo) == LOW || digitalRead(ButtonReset) == LOW) )
  {
  digitalWrite(elevatorReset, HIGH);  // wait for a second
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(elevatorReset, LOW);  // wait for a second
  delay(200);
  }
}
```

Comment: What language do you want to translate the code into?

Comment: Preferably C# to work with Visual Studio and use Windows 10 IoT on the Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, you can still use C++ to develop apps for Win10 IoT.

I built for you a similar one in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private static GpioPin GpioPin1;
        private static GpioPin GpioPin2;
        private static GpioPin GpioPin3;
        private static GpioPin GpioPin4;
        private static GpioPin GpioPin5;
        private static GpioPin GpioPin6;
        private static GpioPin GpioPin7;
        private static GpioPin GpioPin8;

    // Sensors for shelves. True if shelf is loaded.
    bool s1 = false;
    bool s2 = false;

    // Buttons to ask to shelves.
    bool input1 = false;
    bool input2 = false;

    // Elevator level (0, 1, or 2)
    int elevator = 0;

    // Elevator Level LEDs (Red)
    int elevatorReset = 13;
    int elevatorOne = 12;
    int elevatorTwo = 11;

    // Shelve State LEDs (Green) (On if loaded, Off if hidden)
    int ShelveOne = 10; // Top Shelve
    int ShelveTwo = 9; // Bottom Shelve


    // Buttons
    int ButtonOne = 2; // Request Shelve One
    int ButtonTwo = 3; // Request Shelve Two
    int ButtonReset = 4; // Request Reset

    // Debouncing
    long lastTime1 = 0;
    long lastTime2 = 0;
    const long interval = 300;
    private DispatcherTimer timer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

        InitGPIO();
    }

    private void InitGPIO()
    {
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

        // Show an error if there is no GPIO controller
        if (gpio == null)
        {
            GpioPin1 = null;
            GpioPin2 = null;
            GpioPin3 = null;
            GpioPin4 = null;
            GpioPin5 = null;
            GpioPin6 = null;
            GpioPin7 = null;
            GpioPin8 = null;

            return;
        }
        //pinMode(elevatorReset, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output 
        //pinMode(elevatorOne, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output 
        //pinMode(elevatorTwo, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output

        //pinMode(ShelveOne, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output
        //pinMode(ShelveTwo, OUTPUT); // declare LED as output

        //pinMode(ButtonOne, INPUT); // make button 1 an input 
        //pinMode(ButtonTwo, INPUT); // make button 2 an input 
        //pinMode(ButtonReset, INPUT); // make button 3 an input 
        GpioPin1 = gpio.OpenPin(elevatorReset);
        GpioPin2 = gpio.OpenPin(elevatorOne);
        GpioPin3 = gpio.OpenPin(elevatorTwo);
        GpioPin4 = gpio.OpenPin(ShelveOne);
        GpioPin5 = gpio.OpenPin(ShelveTwo);
        GpioPin6 = gpio.OpenPin(ButtonOne);
        GpioPin7 = gpio.OpenPin(ButtonTwo);
        GpioPin8 = gpio.OpenPin(ButtonReset);

        GpioPin1.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        GpioPin2.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        GpioPin3.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        GpioPin4.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        GpioPin5.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);

        GpioPin1.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        GpioPin2.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        GpioPin3.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        GpioPin4.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        GpioPin5.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

        // Check if input pull-up resistors are supported
        if (GpioPin6.IsDriveModeSupported(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp))
            GpioPin6.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp);
        else
            GpioPin6.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);

        if (GpioPin7.IsDriveModeSupported(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp))
            GpioPin7.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp);
        else
            GpioPin7.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);

        if (GpioPin8.IsDriveModeSupported(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp))
            GpioPin8.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp);
        else
            GpioPin8.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);

    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {

        //unsigned long currentTime = millis();

        level(0);

        // Request Shelf 1
        if (GpioPin6.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
        {
            pickup(1);
            deliver(1);
        }

        // Request Shelf 2
        if (GpioPin7.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
        {
            pickup(2);
            deliver(2);
        }

        // Request Reset
        if (GpioPin8.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
        {
            reset();
        }
    }


    async void pickup(int num)
    {
        if (num == 1)
        {
            level(0);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            level(1);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            load(1);
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            level(0);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            level(1);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            level(2);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            load(2);
        }
        else if (num == 0)
        {

        }
    }

    async void dropoff(int num)
    {
        if (num == 1)
        {
            level(1);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            unload(1);
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            level(1);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            level(2);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            unload(2);
        }
    }

    async void deliver(int num)
    {
        if (elevator == 1)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            level(0);
            //blink();
        }

        if (elevator == 2)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            level(1);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            level(0);
            //blink();
        }
    }

    void level(int num)
    {
        if (num == 0)
        {
            GpioPin1.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
            GpioPin2.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            GpioPin3.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            elevator = 0;
        }
        else if (num == 1)
        {
            GpioPin1.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            GpioPin2.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
            GpioPin3.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            elevator = 1;
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            GpioPin1.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            GpioPin2.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            GpioPin3.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
            elevator = 2;
        }
    }

    void load(int num)
    {
        if (num == 1)
        {
            GpioPin4.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
            GpioPin5.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            s1 = true;
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            GpioPin4.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            GpioPin5.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
            s2 = true;
        }
    }

    void unload(int num)
    {
        if (num == 1)
        {
            GpioPin4.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            s1 = false;
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            GpioPin5.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            s2 = false;
        }
    }

    async void reset()
    {
        if (s1 == true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            dropoff(1);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            level(0);
        }

        else if (s2 == true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            dropoff(2);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            level(1);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            level(0);
        }
    }

    async void blink()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        while (!(GpioPin6.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low || GpioPin7.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low || GpioPin8.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low))
        {
            GpioPin1.Write(GpioPinValue.High);  // wait for a second
            await Task.Delay(200);
            GpioPin1.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);  // wait for a second
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There are a few items to realize here

1. IoT Applications have the concept of a background application.  See documentation here: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/BackgroundApplications.htm 
   Note: It says background App, which may be confusing as it does not run like a background app in typical UWP does.  The bootloader for IoT removes performance and cpu priority bottlenecks typically imposed on Background Applications for UWP and therefor runs just like a Foreground Application, just it is headless and a bit of an easier headless starting point.  It also more closely resembles your Arduino code.
2. You should use enums for managing your state so it is centralized and easier to deal with.
3. In windows 10 IoT, you have the ability to setup event handlers for when events happen and process them instead of necessarily looping and watching.  This will help in that events will be queued up and then processed.  It may not be quite as speedy in some scenarios however, but in this instance it should be fine.  If you need to loop, you may want to spin off a task that loops and watches
4. Finally in an event based multi-threaded system, you will need to guard processing state changes simultaneously from different threads by locking an object.

I have provided sample code based on your code base addressing all of the above.  Note it is not completed, but should serve as a good starting point.

First you will need to create a background application and add a reference to the IoT extensions.

[image: Background Application]
[image: Adding IoT Extensions]

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// The Background Application template is documented at       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533884&clcid=0x409
// Sensors for shelves. True if shelf is loaded.

namespace BackgroundApplication1
{
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public enum MachineState
    {
        unknown,
        initial,
        elevatorLevelOne,
        elevatorLevelTwo,
        transitionOnetoTwo,
        transitionTwotoOne,
        transitionOnetoReset,
        transitionTwotoReset
    }
    private MachineState currentState;
    private object lObj;
    // Elevator Level LEDs (Red)
    private const int elevatorResetPin = 13;
    private const int elevatorOnePin = 12;
    private const int elevatorTwoPin = 11;
    //Gpio for each
    GpioPin elevOneLed;
    GpioPin resetLed;
    GpioPin elevTwoLed;

    // Shelve State LEDs (Green) (On if loaded, Off if hidden)
    private const int ShelveOnePin = 10; // Top Shelve
    private const int ShelveTwoPin = 9; // Bottom Shelve
    GpioPin shelfOneLed;
    GpioPin shelfTwoLed;


    // Buttons
    private const int ButtonOne = 2; // Request Shelve One
    private const int ButtonTwo = 3; // Request Shelve Two
    private const int ButtonReset = 4; // Request Reset

    // Debouncing
    long lastTime1 = 0;
    long lastTime2 = 0;
    const long interval = 300;
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        this.Initialize();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //thats right...do nothing.
            }
        });
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        GpioController gCon = GpioController.GetDefault();
        //Elevator LEDs
        elevOneLed = gCon.OpenPin(elevatorResetPin);
        resetLed = gCon.OpenPin(elevatorOnePin);
        elevTwoLed = gCon.OpenPin(elevatorTwoPin);
        elevOneLed.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        elevTwoLed.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        resetLed.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        //Shelf LEDs
        shelfOneLed = gCon.OpenPin(ShelveOnePin);
        shelfTwoLed = gCon.OpenPin(ShelveTwoPin);
        shelfOneLed.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        shelfTwoLed.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

        //Buttons
        GpioPin buttonOne = gCon.OpenPin(ButtonOne);
        GpioPin buttonTwo = gCon.OpenPin(ButtonTwo);
        GpioPin buttonReset = gCon.OpenPin(ButtonReset);
        buttonOne.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);
        buttonTwo.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);
        buttonReset.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);
        buttonOne.ValueChanged += ButtonOne_ValueChanged;
        buttonTwo.ValueChanged += ButtonTwo_ValueChanged;
        buttonReset.ValueChanged += ButtonReset_ValueChanged;

        this.GetShelfOne();
    }

    private void GetShelfOne()
    {

            switch(this.currentState)
            {
                case MachineState.unknown: this.Reset();
                    break;
                case MachineState.elevatorLevelOne: 
                    break;
                case MachineState.elevatorLevelTwo: this.TransitionToShelfTwoFromOne();
                    break;
                case MachineState.transitionOnetoReset: //handle the rest of your stuff similiarly...
                    break;
            }

    }

    private void TransitionToShelfTwoFromOne()
    {
        this.shelfOneLed.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        this.shelfTwoLed.Write(GpioPinValue.High);            
        this.currentState = MachineState.elevatorLevelTwo;
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ButtonReset_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ButtonTwo_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ButtonOne_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //rising edge means you pushed the button
        if(args.Edge == GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge)
        {
            lock(lObj)
            {
                this.GetShelfOne();
            }
        }
        //falling edge means you released the button.
        //you could start a timer to see how long you held the button.
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. Way 1 - You can directly use Arduino code onto your Windows IoT with minor changes.
2. Way 2 - By converting Arduino code into equivalent C# UWP.

**Way 1: Use Arduino code directly on your Windows IoT**

1. Setup Arduino Wiring for Windows IoT ([refer this link](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/ArduinoWiringPortingGuide.htm))
2. Port your Arduino code (written above) onto your Windows IoT with pinmap of Raspberry Pi 2.

   > **Important Note:** There are some rules to port Arduino written code to Windows IoT which is described at [ms-iot website](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/ArduinoWiringPortingGuide.htm). The Arduino code you have provided can directly be ported on to Raspberry Pi 2 (make sure to change Arduino pin numbers to RPi2 pinmap).

**Way 2: Converting Arduino code to C# UWP**
Converting Arduino code into C# UWP is not much complicated. You just have to convert Arduino functions into its equivalent C# UWP Windows IoT functions:

[image]